# Installation Error, "Unable to lock the administration directory"

Tags: installation, software-center, dpkg, lock

Whenever I try to install any software through Terminal or Software on my Ubuntu 11.04, I'm getting this response:

#### In Terminal:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

#### In Software Center

```
An unhandlable error occured
There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.
```

What should I do?